# XAMPP on windows. Apache Shutdown Unexpectedly. Apache not starting

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

This is a common issue where the port is already in use by other applications. But I have corrected the issue from skype where it was using port 80 and 443. But I am not sure what else application might be preventing apache from running.

Here is the error log

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
improper privileges, a crash or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check.
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues.
IF you need more help,
copy and post this entire log window in the forum
```

I have checked the error log file. It would be nice if anyone would kindly explain me the issue. I am new in using xampp

```
[Mon Jan 11 15:41:31.711045 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 6344:tid 768] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 11 15:41:33.542795 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 6344:tid 768] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 11 15:41:37.708844 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6344:tid 768] AH00455: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 11 15:41:37.709343 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6344:tid 768] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Oct 13 2015 10:54:13
[Mon Jan 11 15:41:37.709343 2016] [core:notice] [pid 6344:tid 768] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Jan 11 15:41:37.963876 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6344:tid 768] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5008
[Mon Jan 11 15:41:44.877326 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 5008:tid 688] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 11 15:41:46.246564 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 5008:tid 688] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 11 15:41:46.644423 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5008:tid 688] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: Which version of `xampp` are you using..

Comment: netstat in the xampp shows the ports 80 and 443 are in use by httpd.exe

Comment: first edit your post `But I am noy` to `But I am not`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you **read the messages from Apache** it is quite obvious you have tried to activate SSL and there is a problem with what you have done.

I think this part of the error message from XAMPP is most relevant `a crash or a shutdown by another method.`

Assuming you did this by uncommenting the `Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` line in `httpd.conf` then just comment that line out again and then try and fix your SSL config.

As suggested by the error message, look at the Windows Event Viewer. Apache writes there as well as its log file. SOmetimes the errors shown in Event Viewer are very descriptive and will identify a line number in a config  file where the error exists

**RE Your comment :**

*I had previous installation of xamp on my system. I had deleted the source folder of xampp and reinstalled xampp*

Its possible that as you did not uninstall the old version of XAMPP something from the old version is still registered with your system and that is what is causing this odd situation.

I would uninstall this XAMPP (properly) and then check if you still have an Apache and/or MYSQL service registered, look using the services snapin.

If they are still there you can remove them like this (sc delete ) :-

```
Start command window using "Run as Administrator"
sc delete MYSQL
sc delete Apache
```

Make sure you have backed up any databases, although it may already be to late for this.

Then you can re-install the version of XAMPP you want to use.

Comment: yes the     Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf line is un-commented and I haven't un-commented it. It was there by default. Do you suggest commenting that line?
and how may I use the event viewer in windows?

Comment: Yes, If you comment that line out then you will probably be able to restart Apache again. Is this a new install of XAMPP?

Comment: I have commented the line but with no luck. This is a fresh install of xampp. I have recently downloaded from www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: Are you sure you dont have another Apache on your system? Did you try installing Apache/MySQL/PHP manually before finding XAMPP?

Comment: no I haven't installed Apache/MySQL/PHP anything, but I had previous installation of xamp on my system. I had deleted the source folder of xampp and reinstalled xampp. can that be a reason  for conflicts for apache. ?

Comment: It is always better to UNINSTALL properly rather than just delete the xampp folder.

Comment: I can see 2 processes of httpd.exe running in the task manager with different PID. Does that have anything to do with my failure to run apache?

Comment: No 2 pids for Apache are normal

Comment: See additional suggestion, now we know what may be causing the issue

Comment: So I am going to uninstall this installation of xampp and try again. But the uninstaller never seems to work. Don't know why that happens. so the only option is to delete the source folder.

Comment: Thats probably because of how you badly uninstalled the previous version.

Comment: I have tried to use the command prompt sc delete MYSQL and sc delete APACHE. 
but no use. I have next installed the xamp in a different directory. But still the same case.
I see IIS 10.0 Express is already installed in the system. Can it be interfering with APACHE?

Comment: Yes it probably woudl interfere, if its actually running. they both use port 80

Comment: Finally worked. I have installed xampp in a different dir. However, as I start the control panel, 2 services with with different pid's starts. which are encountered in the task manager. Apache logs problems about one of the pid's in the services list. as soon as I end the services and hit start on apache in the control panel the apache starts and with different pids than the ones stopped in the services in TM. I have also deleted some values from the regedit that corresponds to the previous installation of xampp in a previous directory in a different drive.
But Thanks to you for the help.